# Docker build can't find NETFramework Version 5

Tags: asp.net, docker, centos

I use a system with CentOS to host my ASP.NET Core API. I wanted to realise this with Docker. I then installed the necessary SDKs on my server.

```
sudo dnf install dotnet-sdk-5.0
```

This is the current State.

[image]

Then i created a Dockerfile that looks like this.

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:latest

COPY ./coinz-api /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN ["dotnet", "restore"]
RUN ["dotnet", "build"]

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://*:5001

EXPOSE 5001

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "run"]
```

When I try to build the Docker container this happens.

[image]

In my opinion, the required SDK and its runtimes are installed. So where is the error? Do I have the wrong versions?

EDIT: Here is my target. (Sorry its in German...)

[image]

Comment: To debug this, can you add a `RUN ["dotnet", "--info"]` in your `Dockerfile` before the `RUN ["dotnet", "restore"]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using an out of date container:

```
$ podman run -it docker.io/microsoft/dotnet:latest dotnet --info
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   2.1.816
 Commit:    f03a7f8e72

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     debian
 OS Version:  9
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         debian.9-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.816/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 2.1.28
  Commit:  612cb8b183

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.1.816 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.28 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.28 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.28 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

This is a .NET Core 2.1 container image!

You should use a newer .NET container image. The newer .NET container images are published at mcr.microsoft.com. [The official .NET on docker docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/docker/building-net-docker-images?view=aspnetcore-5.0#build-and-deploy-manually) suggest something like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0
```

That said, if you want your container image to match the CentOS host, you can also start with a CentOS container image install the .NET SDK in there. Maybe something like this?

```
FROM registry.centos.org/centos:8

RUN "sudo dnf install -y dotnet-sdk-5.0"
```